# Playframework + Morphia + MongoDb + ElasticSearch = Disater?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia, elasticsearch

Guys I have a couple of questions:

Q1. I am using Play 1.1.1 with the Morphia-MongoDB module and ElasticSearch for Indexing. Has any one tried this?

Q2. For some reason the morphia plugin (versions beta4 & beta5) are erroring out in the ObjectIdBinder class. Apparently it does not like @Override on the bind method. Has anyone else faced this? What is the fix?

Comment: Hi Drunken Programmer I am developing the module for ElasticSearch and Play!, please let me know if I can help you with that. I am releasing a new version today with a sample search page. There are a lot of features to be added still though.

Comment: hey! how has this worked out for you? i've just been using the exact same combination and it seems very trouble free now.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried ElasticSearch before.

To answer your Q2, do you mean you are using morphia beta4 & 5 with play-1.1.1? could you please try the new morhpia beta6?